# Why are my parameters coming into to my controller as 0?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a .NET Core app and I am using ajax to access a controller, pass two parameters, and then open the view. When I pass one parameter via my ajax call everything works fine and the parameter is received by the controller as the right value. When I pass two both parameters are 0. They are not 0 when they are submitted via the ajax call. Something happens between the ajax call and the controller that converts both parameters to 0. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Ajax CAll:

id and orderId both show up here as the correct values.

```
 if (id != undefined) {
        id = Number(id);
    } else {
        id = 0;
    };

    var orderId = Number(document.getElementById('orderId').value);

    var data = JSON.stringify({       
        'id': id,
        'orderId': orderId       
    });
   
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AddorEditTask/OpenTaskForm",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { id: id, orderId: orderId },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Unable to open task form. " + e.responseText);
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        //alert(data.newUrl);
        window.location.replace(data.newUrl);
    });
```

Controller:

id and orderId both show up here as 0.

```
[HttpPost] //Being used in AJAX call to all the "AddorEdit" GET action and open the task form.
    public ActionResult OpenTaskForm(int id,int orderId)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            newUrl = Url.Action("AddorEditTask", new { id = id, orderId = orderId })
        }
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _data: { "id": id, "orderId": orderId },_

Comment: I have tried that and I have tried stringify the data into a json object like: 
    var data = JSON.stringify({       
        'id': id,
        'orderId': orderId       
    });
And that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was making a 'post' request instead of a 'get' request and that was causing the issue. I updated my controller to look like:

```
[HttpGet] //Being used in AJAX call to all the "AddorEdit" GET action and open the task form.
    public ActionResult OpenTaskForm(int id,int orderId)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            newUrl = Url.Action("AddorEditTask", new { id = id, orderId = orderId })
        }
        );
    }
```

My ajax call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/AddorEditTask/OpenTaskForm",
    type: 'GET',    
    data: { "id": id, "orderId": orderId },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Unable to open task form. " + e.responseText);
        console.log(e.responseText);
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    //alert(data.newUrl);
    window.location.replace(data.newUrl);
});
```